# Открыть последнюю активити после перезапуска

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Как заставить приложение открываться на последней запущенной активити после перезапуска по ярлыку? приложение при этом висит в памяти и не закрыто.  Понимаю что это должно быть реализовано через методы Save/Restore InstanceState, но как использовать их в этом случае не пойму.

Comment: это стандартное поведение системы Android

Comment: По умолчанию да, стандартное, вопрос в том как сделать чтоб открывалось на последней запущенной

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `SharedPreferences` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: Сделал через SharedPreferences - вроде работает!